# OracleCommand SQL Parameter not working

Tags: c#, oracle

My code looks likes this:

```
String Tablei= "PHGR_PHYS_GRAPH";
OracleCommand cmd_row = new OracleCommand();
OracleDataReader dr1;
cmd_row.CommandText = "SELECT PHGR_ID FROM " +":tableconf";
cmd_row.Connection = conn;
cmd_row.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("tableconf", Tablei));
dr1 = cmd_row.ExecuteReader();
```

and i get error ORA-00903 invalid table name.

However when i change the query like this(without parameter):

```
cmd_row.CommandText = "SELECT PHGR_ID FROM PHGR_PHYS_GRAPH";
```

works. 
Can anyone point me out what is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `OracleParameter` for this purpose. You can use this for parameter values only. For example:

```
OracleCommand cmd_row = new OracleCommand();
cmd_row.CommandText = "SELECT PHGR_ID FROM PHGR_PHYS_GRAPH WHERE phgr_id=:phgr_id";
cmd_row.Connection = conn;
cmd_row.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("phgr_id", "some_value"));
```

If you want to have a variable table name you should use `String.Format()` or the more concise `$`

```
String Tablei= "PHGR_PHYS_GRAPH";
OracleCommand cmd_row = new OracleCommand();
cmd_row.CommandText = $"SELECT PHGR_ID FROM {Tablei} WHERE phgr_id=:phgr_id";
cmd_row.Connection = conn;
cmd_row.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("phgr_id", "some_value"));
```

BTW: I strongly recommend to wrap your code in using blocks