# How to call an Oracle system stored proc from a c# EF API?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I need to call two system stored procedures in an Oracle database to refresh materialised views when a C# API executes a related process.  My code attempts to do so get the following error:

```
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 236
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 256
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 3016
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

My last attempt was this:

```
            string command= "dbms_snapshot.refresh";
            string mv1 = "MV_00";
            string mv2 = "MV_01";
            string parameter = String.Concat(mv1, ", ", mv2);
            //we pull the connection here from an EF datamodel
            using (var cnx = (OracleConnection)new DataModel().Database.Connection)
            using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(command, cnx))
        
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter, OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                await cnx.OpenAsync();
                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                cnx.Close();
            }
```

The error text in c# indicates something is wrong with the parameter value.  What am I doing wrong here?  I understand how parameters work, that is not the question, simply what is wrong with my comma separated list that would throw the error back up the stack.

Comment: This question shows how to use an oracle parameter. It doesn't look quite like what you have here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50830965/oraclecommand-sql-parameter-not-working

Comment: That doesn't in the least answer the question.  The question is why the parameter, which is a varchar2 going into the database stored procedure which is awaiting a string list separated by commas, is  not accepting the string concatenated in c#.

Comment: And the answer of the linked question shows the person creating a parameter as a new OracleParameter(paramerName, parameterValue)
Nothing like that was done here. This should actually be closed as duplicate question